# amadeus.shopping.flight_dates.get(origin='JTR', destination='SFO', ...) fails

Tags: amadeus

```py
response = amadeus.shopping.flight_dates.get(origin='JTR', destination='SFO', oneWay='true', departureDate='2019-05-01,2019-06-01', nonStop=False)
```

This returns an error.

```
*** amadeus.client.errors.ServerError: [500]
```

This is not an auth error or some other parameter error, since the exact same code with different airport codes works.

```py
response = amadeus.shopping.flight_dates.get(origin='NYC', destination='SFO', oneWay='true', departureDate='2019-05-01,2019-06-01', nonStop=False)
```

The client is using a production key and has hostname set to production.

```py
Client(client_id=get_api_key(), client_secret=get_api_secret(), hostname='production')
```

Answer (score 1):

The Flight Cheapest Date Search API is built on top of a pre-computed cache, it doesn't contain all the origins and destinations. The Flight Low-fare Search will provide you a coverage of (almost) all airports in the world.

We will update soon the data coverage we have for this API to drastically improve the list of origins and destinations.

That's why:

> response = amadeus.shopping.flight_dates.get(origin='JTR', destination='SFO', oneWay='true', departureDate='2019-05-01,2019-06-01', nonStop=False)

Doesn't return any data.

For:

> response = amadeus.shopping.flight_dates.get(origin='NYC', destination='SFO', oneWay='true', departureDate='2019-05-01,2019-06-01', nonStop=False)

It works, in production it returns a list of flight-dates.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What is the timeline for the update?

Comment: Also it would be good if the error indicated that this data is not available for a pair of destinations rather than being a generic error. That way at least a developer knows they should try to handle this as just data being absent, rather than an API error.

Comment: The engineering team is working on it, I will update this thread when I have a final date. For the 500 error, in the "detail" you have this message ""detail":"DATA DOMAIN NOT FOUND FOR REQUEST"". let me know if you think the error message is not clear enough.